# <?php wp_head(); ?> Breaks all jquery sliders on page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Here is the test server I am working on:

http://www.astwood.co.uk/testsite/wordpress/

I have set up two sliders using liquidSlider (a responsive fork of coda slider) in two of the three red boxes. That break when I put the

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

hook in the

```
<head>
```

tag.

Can anyone take a look and see if they can shine some light on why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. But I’m sure the Console in a browser like Google Chrome will be able to tell you why.

Comment: How are you inserting your jQuery scripts? Please post relevant code from `functions.php` or `header.php`.

Comment: @AlexandruChelariu the OP is referring to the [**`wp_head()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) template tag, *not* the [`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) include tag (which includes the `header.php` file, *not* the `<head></head>` HTML tags directly).

Answer (score 0):

You've got two instances of the jQuery script on the page! This can create a lot of conflicts and confusion. Either you or one of your plugins is linking to jQuery without using the proper [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function.

I'm gonna go ahead and point the finger at Advanced Ajax Page Loader. Try deactivating that plugin and see if your sliders start working. I've looked into it, and that plugin actually does a decent job of enqueueing the script:

```
function enqueue_AAPL() {
    //Make sure we use latest jquery?
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', plugins_url( 'jquery.js' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

So my guess is that you've included `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.astwood.co.uk/testsite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/AstwoodV3/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>` somewhere in your header file. Find it, take it out. Then make sure you're enqueueing all your scripts (like jQueryUI, fancybox, liquid-slider, jquery.tweet, etc.) keeping in mind the `dependencies` parameter